# setting Password pattern for validation of Password in android

Tags: android, validation, android-layout, android-edittext, password-protection

I want to create password pattern in android that contain below thing

- Upper Case Character
- Lower Case Character
- Special Character
- Number
- and minimum of 8 digits.

I have used **html5** password pattern

```
String password_pattern = "(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\\d)|(?=.*\\W+))(?![.\\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$";
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})";
```

Description of Pattern

```
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])   #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])   #   must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])   #   must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
              . #   match anything with previous condition checking
  {6,20}        #   length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20
```

You can use like this

```
public boolean validate(final String password){

        return PASSWORD_PATTERN.matches(password);
}
```

For detail please [Check this](https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/)

Answer (score 4):

Try with below Regex, it can allow what you need like,

**1.** Upper Letter

**2.** Lower Letter

**3.** Special Character

**4.** Number

**5.** minimum 8 digit

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$
```

Check this link :

https://regex101.com/r/S7cd5A/1

Comment: does not even accept the valid password.

Comment: @ManXoor check it work the link is define.